# How can I build FreeBSD from source correctly?

Tags: unix, makefile, freebsd, bsd

I am trying to build FreeBSD from source to see how it works. I googled how to do it, and most of the websites explaining how to build the world tell me to run this command inside the directory of the source code:

```
sudo make -j1 buildworld KERNCONF=MODEDKERNEL -DNO_CLEAN
```

For some reason, I keep getting this error...

```
make: invalid option -- 'D'
make: invalid option -- 'N'
```

Anyone know how to fix this? The `Makefile` can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/main/Makefile)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't need to see the makefile, because this error is being printed by make due to an invalid command line argument which means it's never even opening the makefile before it fails.

The reason is that `-D`, etc. are not valid command line options to GNU make.  If you run `man make` (or look online for the GNU `make` manual) you'll see that `-D` is not listed as a valid option.

My suspicion is that when the websites you are reading are suggesting that you run `make`, they mean you should run FreeBSD make, which does support a `-D` option: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?make(1)

You are trying to run this using GNU make, which does not have that option.

Comment: In other words, these tutorials are assuming you're trying to build FreeBSD from source _using a FreeBSD system_.  But you're trying to build FreeBSD from source using some other operating system, probably GNU/Linux (or maybe MacOS).  That's a very different set of steps.  Maybe you'll find a tutorial for that, too, but you'll have to be explicit that that's what you want, when you do your searching.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks